# Can C++ variables in cpp file defined as Special Symbols β

Tags: c++, c++11, variables, visual-c++

Can we define the variable in C++/C using special characters
such as;

```
double ε,µ,β,ϰ;
```

If yes, how can this be achieved?

Comment: Full answer here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers

Comment: You can use macros to define them as something else. For instance, `#define β beta`, then use `β` as the name of an identifier. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: There is no such thing as C/C++. These are two different languages with different rules. Pleaae decide which language you want to use and update your tags accordingly.

Comment: try to use compilation option  `-fextended-identifiers`. For more info check answers here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799078/why-doesnt-these-unicode-variable-names-work-with-fextended-identifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799078/why-doesnt-these-unicode-variable-names-work-with-fextended-identifiers)
 [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692067/and-other-unicode-characters-in-identifiers-not-allowed-by-g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692067/and-other-unicode-characters-in-identifiers-not-allowed-by-g)

Comment: @stackoverflower: Wrong compiler - this is tagged visual C++

Comment: Sort of a duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799078/why-doesnt-these-unicode-variable-names-work-with-fextended-identifiers. Doesn't mention Greek explicitly, but the top answer does reflect P.W.'s answer below.

Comment: @Gerhardh: While that's true, C and C++ both are ISO languages and follow basic rules from another ISO standard, ISO/IEC TR 10176 "Guidelines for the preparation of programming language standards." which in turn refers to ISO 10646 aka Unicode.

Comment: @MSalters this does not mean that they have exactly the same rules where those unicode characters may be used. In ISO/IEC 9899:2011 I cannot find anything about an identifier not starting with a `universal-character-name` in a certain range.

Comment: @Gerhardh: It's true they don't have the exact same rules, but given that both C and C++ base their rules on the same ISO standard, this is one of those rare cases where it does make sense to ask about C and C++ at the same time. Remember, this is no coincidence. WG14 and WG21 coordinate in these matters.

Answer (score 7):

As per the working draft of CPP standard (N4713),

> 5.10 Identifiers [lex.name]
>   ...
>   An identifier is an arbitrarily long sequence of letters and digits. Each universal-character-name in an identifier shall designate a character whose encoding in ISO 10646 falls into one of the ranges specified in Table 2. **The initial element shall not be a universal-character-name designating a character whose encoding falls into one of the ranges specified in Table 3.**

And when we look at table 3:

> Table 3 — Ranges of characters disallowed initially (combining characters)
>
> ```
> 0300-036F 1DC0-1DFF 20D0-20FF FE20-FE2F
> ```

The symbols you have mentioned are the Greek Alphabet which ranges from `U+0370` to `U+03FF` and the extended Greek set ranges from `U+1F0x` to `U+1FFx` as per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters). Both these ranges are allowed as the initial element of an identifier.

**Note that not all compilers provide support for this.**

GCC 8.2 with `-std=c++17` option fails to compile.
However, Clang 7.0 with `-std=c++17` option compiles.

<kbd>[**Live Demo for both GCC and Clang**](https://godbolt.org/z/zscAA9)</kbd>

Comment: Any character not in those ranges is allowed? `U+0370` to `U+03FF` is not in the range you quoted (`0300-036F` ends just before).

Comment: It makes sense that `0300-036F` is excluded. Those are combining characters/diacriticals, such as the ` in à. Per Unicode standards, combining marks should **follow** the character they modify, which logically excludes them from the begin of any other unicode string, not just C++ identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use special characters, but not all of them. You can find the allowed one in the link below.

You can find a detailed explanation on how to built identifier (with the list of unicode authorized characters) on the page [Identifiers - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers).

An identifier is, quoting,

> an arbitrarily long sequence of digits, underscores, lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and most Unicode characters (see below for details). A valid identifier must begin with a non-digit character (Latin letter, underscore, or Unicode non-digit character). Identifiers are case-sensitive (lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct), and every character is significant.

Furthermore, Unicode characters need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged Visual Studio: Just write the code as you'd expect it.

`double β = 0.1;`

When you save the file, Visual Studio will warn you that it needs to save the file as Unicode. Accept it, and it works. AFAICT, this also works in C mode, even though most other C99 extensions are unsupported in Visual Studio.

However, as of g++ 8.2, g++ still does not support non-ASCII characters used directly in identifiers, so the code is then effectively not portable.